# python code after finally is not running

Tags: python

I am trying to return an array.

I can print the messages array to the console, and I can see it getting populated.
However code after the finally appears to be unreachable. What am I doing wrong?

```
def kafka_messages(topic, partition):
    messages = []

    try:
        consumer = SimpleConsumer(kafka, b"consumer-group"
                                  , bytes(topic, "UTF-8")
                                  , partitions=[partition])
        consumer.provide_partition_info()
        consumer.seek(0, 0)

        for message in consumer:
            messages.append(message) # Messages has values

    finally:
        if kafka:
            kafka.close()

    print(messages) # Never even gets run
    return messages
```

Comment: What does `kafka.close()` do? Is it perhaps hanging? Or is the `consumer` iterator perhaps endless?

Comment: The ```consumer``` iterator appears to be infinite

Comment: That looks like somewhere in the code, exceptions are being swallowed. Add a `print()` statement directly before `finally:` so you can be sure the loop terminates properly

Comment: @JohnDoe: well, there's your answer then.

Comment: Step through it in the debugger. You are using a debugger, aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this behavior:

1. The loop doesn't terminate (i.e. `consumer` doesn't stop returning elements)
2. The code throws an exception.

Add a `print('Loop terminated')` right before the line `finally:` to find out if the loop terminates.

If if doesn't, then you need to read the documentation for `SimpleConsumer` to find out how to check whether it has more elements so you can terminate the loop.

**[EDIT]** Looking at the [source for SimpleConsumer](https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/consumer/simple.py), it seems that there is a timeout (default is `ITER_TIMEOUT_SECONDS`) when there is no message but the code looks odd/broken: If `iter_timeout is None`, then the code will sleep and the loop never terminates.

So try to set `iter_timeout` to something small when you create the instance and the loop should stop.

Comment: SimpleConsumer returns a count of elements and I used that to break out of the loop

Comment: @JohnDoe: You should post your solution as well, otherwise people will wonder what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
def kafka_messages(topic, partition):
    messages = []

    try:
        consumer = SimpleConsumer(kafka, b"consumer-group"
                                  , bytes(topic, "UTF-8")
                                  , partitions=[partition])
        consumer.provide_partition_info()
        consumer.seek(0, 0)
        pending = consumer.pending(partitions=[partition]) # Comes with the API being used

        count = 1
        for message in consumer:
            if count == pending:
                break # Simply break out when you have iterated through all the items
            messages.append(message)
            count += 1

    finally:
        if kafka:
            kafka.close()

    return messages
```